# How to override vuetify styling in a specifc component?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to remove the padding from the `v-text-field` component. but I want this change to be applied only in a single vue file not globally. updating the `variables.scss` file works but it removes the padding from all the `v-text-field` components in the whole website which I don't want.

here is what I'm trying but it is not working

test.vue

```
<template>
  <v-text-field
          placeholder="What are you looking for"
          outliend
          filled
  ></v-text-field>
</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
$text-field-enclosed-details-padding: 0;
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a class:

```html
<template>
  <v-text-field
    class="custom-field"
    placeholder="What are you looking for"
    outliend
    filled
  ></v-text-field>
</template

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.custom-field {
  padding: 0px!important;
}
</style>
```

And if you want more customization, please use your own theme in Vuetify object in main.js: [documentation here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/theme/).

Comment: Adding Custom class doesn't work either